# Very slow simple JOIN query

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

Simple DB structure (for an online forum):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    username text
);
CREATE INDEX ON users (username);

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    thread_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES threads (id),
    user_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
    date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    content text
);
CREATE INDEX ON posts (thread_id);
CREATE INDEX ON posts (user_id);
```

Around 80k entries in `users` and 2,6 million entries in `posts` tables. This simple query to get top 100 users by their posts takes **2,4 seconds**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT u.id, u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS PostCount FROM users u
                    INNER JOIN posts p on p.user_id = u.id
                    WHERE u.username IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY PostCount DESC LIMIT 100;
```

```
Limit  (cost=316926.14..316926.39 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=2326.812..2326.830 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=316926.14..317014.83 rows=35476 width=20) (actual time=2326.809..2326.820 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(p.id)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=315215.51..315570.27 rows=35476 width=20) (actual time=2311.296..2321.739 rows=34608 loops=1)
              Group Key: u.id
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1176.89..308201.88 rows=1402727 width=16) (actual time=16.538..1784.546 rows=1910831 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (p.user_id = u.id)
                    ->  Seq Scan on posts p  (cost=0.00..286185.34 rows=1816634 width=8) (actual time=0.103..1144.681 rows=2173916 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=733.44..733.44 rows=35476 width=12) (actual time=15.763..15.763 rows=34609 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 2021kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on users u  (cost=0.00..733.44 rows=35476 width=12) (actual time=0.033..6.521 rows=34609 loops=1)
                                Filter: (username IS NOT NULL)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 11335

Execution time: 2301.357 ms
```

With `set enable_seqscan = false` even worse:

```
Limit  (cost=1160881.74..1160881.99 rows=100 width=20) (actual time=2758.086..2758.107 rows=100 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1160881.74..1160970.43 rows=35476 width=20) (actual time=2758.084..2758.098 rows=100 loops=1)
        Sort Key: (count(p.id)) DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.79..1159525.87 rows=35476 width=20) (actual time=0.095..2749.859 rows=34608 loops=1)
              Group Key: u.id
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.79..1152157.48 rows=1402727 width=16) (actual time=0.036..2537.064 rows=1910831 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: (u.id = p.user_id)
                    ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users u  (cost=0.29..2404.83 rows=35476 width=12) (actual time=0.016..41.163 rows=34609 loops=1)
                          Filter: (username IS NOT NULL)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 11335
                    ->  Index Scan using posts_user_id_index on posts p  (cost=0.43..1131472.19 rows=1816634 width=8) (actual time=0.012..2191.856 rows=2173916 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.281 ms
Execution time: 2758.187 ms
```

Group by `username` is missing in Postgres, because it's not required (SQL Server says I have to group by `username` if I want to select username). Grouping with `username` adds a little bit of ms to execution time on Postgres or does nothing.

For science, I've installed Microsoft SQL Server to the same server (which runs archlinux, 8 core xeon, 24 gb ram, ssd) and migrated all the data from Postgres - *same* table structure, *same* indices, *same* data. *Same* query to get top 100 posters runs in **0,3 seconds**:

```
SELECT TOP 100 u.id, u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS PostCount FROM dbo.users u
                    INNER JOIN dbo.posts p on p.user_id = u.id
                    WHERE u.username IS NOT NULL
                    GROUP BY u.id, u.username
ORDER BY PostCount DESC
```

Yields *same* results from the same data, but does it 8 times faster. And it's beta version of MS SQL on Linux, I guess running on it's "home" OS - Windows Server - it could be faster still.

Is my PostgreSQL query totally wrong, or is PostgreSQL just slow?

#### Additional info

Version is almost the newest (9.6.1, currently newest is 9.6.2, ArchLinux just has outdated packages and is very slow to update). Config:

```
max_connections = 75
shared_buffers = 3584MB       
effective_cache_size = 10752MB
work_mem = 24466kB         
maintenance_work_mem = 896MB   
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` outputs: https://pastebin.com/HxucRgnk

Tried all the indexes, used even GIN and GIST, fastest way for PostgreSQL (and Googling confirms with many rows) is to use sequential scan.

MS SQL Server 14.0.405.200-1, default conf.

I use this in an API (with plain select without analyze), and calling this API endpoint with chrome it says it takes 2500 ms +-, add 50 ms of HTTP and web server overhead overhead (API and SQL run on the same server) - it's the same. I do not care about 100 ms here or there, what I care about is two whole seconds.

`explain analyze SELECT user_id, count(9) FROM posts group by user_id;` takes 700 ms. Size of `posts` table is is 2154 MB.

Comment: As it sounds, you have nice fat posts from your users (~ 1kB on average).  It might make sense to detach them from the rest of the `posts` table, using a table like `CREATE TABLE post_content (post_id PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES posts (id), content text);`  That way, most of the I/O that is 'wasted' on this type of queries could be spared.  If the posts are smaller than this, a `VACUUM FULL` on `posts` can help.

Comment: Yes, posts have content column which has all the html of a post. Thank you for your suggestion, will try that tomorrow. Question is - MSSQL posts table also weighs over 1.5 GB and has same entries in content, but manages to be quite faster - why?

Comment: You could possibly post an actual execution plan from SQL Server, too.  Might be really interesting, even to Postgres people like myself.

Comment: Hmm, quick guesss, could you change this `GROUP BY u.id` to this `GROUP BY p.user_id` and try that? My guess is, that Postgres does join first and group by second because you are grouping by users table identifier, even though you need only posts user_id to get the top N - rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another good query variant is:

```
SELECT p.user_id, p.cnt AS PostCount
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
    select user_id, count(id) as cnt from posts group by user_id
) as p on p.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.username IS NOT NULL          
ORDER BY PostCount DESC LIMIT 100;
```

It doesn't exploit CTE and gives correct answer (and CTE example may produce less than 100 rows in theory cause it first limits then joins with users).

I suppose, MSSQL able to perform such transformation in its query optimizer, and PostgreSQL is not able to push down aggregation under join.
Or MSSQL just have much faster hash join implementation.

Answer (score 8):

This may or may not work - I'm basing this off a gut feeling that it's joining your tables before the group and filter. I suggest trying the following: filter and group using a CTE before attempting the join:

```
with
    __posts as(
        select
            user_id,
            count(1) as num_posts
        from
            posts
        group by
            user_id
        order by
            num_posts desc
        limit 100
    )
select
    users.username,
    __posts.num_posts
from
    users
    inner join __posts on(
        __posts.user_id = users.id
    )
order by
    num_posts desc
```

The query planner sometimes just needs a little guidance. This solution works well here, but CTEs can potentially be terrible in some circumstances. CTEs are stored exclusively in memory. As a result of this, large data returns can exceed Postgres' allocated memory and start swapping (paging in MS). CTEs also cannot be indexed, so a sufficiently large query could still cause significant slow down when querying your CTE.

The best advice you can really take away is to try it multiple ways and check your query plans.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to increase work_mem?
24Mb seems to be too small and so Hash Join has to use multiple batches (which are written in temp files).

Comment: It isn't too small. Increasing to 240 megabytes does nothing. What would help in postgresql.conf is enabling parallel queries by adding these two lines: `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4` and `max_worker_processes = 16`